# How to get or create a .fig file in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

How can one generate a .fig file ? 
I am getting an error in the function gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:}), its looking for .fig file. Please help me

Comment: Are you using GUIDE  to create the GUI? If so, the ".m" and ".fig" files of the GUI  are automatically  create when you save the GUI. By default they have the same name (a part fro the extension" and are stored in the same folder. Did you rename or move any of them?

Comment: I firstly created a .m file then I wrote code inside but when I run it the function "gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});"gives me an error which is basically looking for a .fig file. Please help me if there is something wrong I am doing

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do. You should post the relevant code. Are you openng the GUI from a ".m" file? Did you create the GUI with GUIDE?  How do you open (run) the GUI? You should not directly call "gui_mainfcn"; to open a GUI you have to call the ".m" generate by GUIDE.